# Ruby On Rails Model has no methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a belongs to relationship.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price, :request_id, :url

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :request

end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :keyword

  # Relationships
  has_many :products

end
```

This is the code in my controller function
         product = Product.where({ :asin => asin }).first

```
     # See if the product exists
     begin
         #This throws a method not found error for where
        product = Product.where({ :name => name }).first

     rescue 
        Product.new
             # This throws a method not found error for request_id
        product.request_id = request.id
        product.save
     end
```

I'm trying to create a new product object like so
    product = Product.first(:conditions => { :name => name })

When I call that I get an error saying `undefined method 'first' for Product:Class`
I tried doing Product.new and I can't access any attributes.  I get this for every one `undefined method 'request_id=' for #<Product:0x007ffce89aa7f8>`

I've been able to save request objects.  What am I doing wrong with products?

EDIT:

So as it turns out there was an old Product data type that was being imported that wasn't an ActiveRecord class.  It was using that instead of my Product::ActiveRecord.  I deleted that import and it's good to go.  Sorry to have wasted everybody's time.

Not sure what the proper protocol is here for what to do with this question.

Comment: `product = Product.where(:conditions => {:name => name}).first`

Comment: You said you're trying to "create a new product" but you're calling `.first` which is for selecting a `Product`. If you're trying to initialize a new `Product` with a given name, you should use the following: `product = Product.new(:name => name)`

Comment: I'm trying to create a new product (empty) with Product.new.  That's not working.  I tried the Product.where and got this undefined method `where' for Product:Class

Comment: Did you forget to run your migration(s)?

Comment: Nope. The database table has all the proper columns.

Comment: A more detailed example of what you're doing in your console is in order here. It's really hard to figure out what you're attempting to do here.

Comment: I'm just trying to search/create a new product using the product model.  For some reason it has no methods.  What do you need to see in the console?

Comment: Obviously, your code is legit and like you said migration worked.

Comment: That's why I'm confused.  They seem like a relatively simple models.  Why does one work and save to the database while the other throws an error on any method I try to call?  It's like the model isn't being recognized.  Is there something I need to do to make sure it's included in the controller?

Comment: My guess is your model doesn't map to your table correctly(which might be the case). How about explicitly put `self.table_name = [product_table_name]` inside Product model?Just a test though

Comment: Just tried it. No dice.  I can do all the Product creation and saving in the console using the same code that's failing in the controller.  Really frustrating.

Comment: :), in that case, I reckon the problem is inside your controller not the model itself. If you update the question with the controller code like @demondeac11 has asked, it will help(When you are in console, you  cannot interact with any code in controller btw)

Answer (score 2):

Is your `Product` class an ActiveRecord::Base class?  You can find out by running:

```
Product.ancestors.include?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

If this returns false, it's getting the class loaded from somewhere else.

Comment: I edited the question above.  Not sure if I need to delete it or not.  The problem was exactly that I had an old import bringing in a different Product class.

Answer (score 1):

First check to see that your Product class is set up correctly by typing in:

```
rails c
# after console has loaded
Product
```

If this looks correct then we will try to instantiate a product by calling:

```
# Create a new product
product = Product.new(name: "first product", price: 100, url: "http://www.example.com")
# Persist this object to the database
product.save
```

If you are missing any attributes run another migration to add them to the Product table.

If none of those suggestions work, check to make sure that there isn't an existing class with the same name in your project. This would cause all kinds of errors and would explain certain methods not being found.

Comment: The console dumps out the Product model fine.  If I try to pass any parameters to Product.new I get this `wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`

Comment: Can you print out exactly what you are doing from the console?

Comment: I was running the product creation code in the controller.  I can create and save a product in the console using the exact code I'm using in the controller.  But in the controller I get an error every time I try to do anything with the Product class.

Comment: Could you please post the code that you have in your controller.

Comment: `Product.new`
`product.request_id = 1 #exists in db`
`product.name = "Test"`
`product.save`

Comment: `Product.where(:name => "Test")` Throws a no method found error as well.

Comment: Ok, now we know the problem. I am assuming you are wanting to create a new product through some form in your application. The attributes you enter will be passed to your controller as a params hash. You want to grab those values and create a new product from them. The resulting code should look something like: Product.new(params[:product])

Comment: I'm actually creating them hard coded right now, not in a form.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to find an existing record that has a request_id of 1. I am a little confused by your workflow.

Comment: If the product exists I want to update it.  Otherwise I want to create a new product with a request id of 1 and save it.

Comment: Try something like: product = Product.where(`whatever condition`).first_or_intialize . To check if it is an existing record you can call product.persisted? and then handle the logic around that

Comment: I can't call where on the Product class.  Says it doesn't exist.  The product model apparently doesn't have any methods.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25113/discussion-between-demondeac11-and-btate)